# Need to verify and validate the resulted JSON produced by the script is correct with sample static JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

I have a script that generates JSON (`values` will be assigned to predefined `keys`) as output and uploads it to the cloud. I need to write a routine as a test script that validates the `values` are correct places to the `key` of the JSON. If the test script result is `True` only need to proceed to upload the result to the cloud.

Below I will share a predefined sample JSON that will act as the spine of the test script which needs to compare the output of the script with the sample JSON.

```
{
   "first_name":"",
   "last_name":"",
   "age":"",
   "dob":"",
   "address":[
      {
         "address1":"",
         "address2":""
      }
   ],
   "mobile":"",
   "telephone":"",
   "education":[
       {
          "primary_education":"",
          "seconday_education":"",
          "high_school":"",
          "university":""
       }
   ],
   "work_experience":[
       {
          "company_name":"",
          "company_address":"",
          "position":"",
          "joined_date":"",
          "resigned_date":""
       },
       {
          "company_name":"",
          "company_address":"",
          "position":"",
          "joined_date":"",
          "resigned_date":""
       }
   ]
}
```

Top of my head I'm struggling to write the algorithm/ test script to achieve this task in python. please help me out with this thread. I'm stuck with this for days and I have come to stack overflow to seek a good solution

Comment: It sounds to me like `jsonschema` (https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) might do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @JonSG what can we do from this. please explain that would be a great help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jsonschema` package probably provides everything you are looking to do validation wise. https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/

A call to:

```
jsonschema.validate(instance=my_json_text, schema=schema_text)
```

will tell if you have "good" `my_json_text`.

As a brief example, your `schema_text` might be:

```
{
    "type" : "object",

    "required" : [
        "ID",
        "name",
        "url"
    ],

    "properties" : {
        "ID" : {"type" : "string", "minLength" : 1},
        "name" : {"type" : "string", "minLength" : 10},
        "url" : {"type" : "string", "minLength" : 20}
    }
}
```

This says that the root element has certain required fields and further, those fields must be of a certain type and of certain lengths. The schema validation supports nested json and arrays and bool and whatnot. We use it a lot to validate complex data returned from graphql endpoints for testing and data processing as a sanity check prior to more intensive stages of our pipelines. This little example is just the "tip of the iceberg", but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good examples on stack overflow where two json objects are compared, so this may not be the best but I think it gets to what you are asking. Because the json is small and I'm assuming the keys won't change between the 'spine' and the 'test' data, here's a routine that outputs True/False for each nested key.

First define the datasets, then I create list of tuples to compare.

```
spine =  {
   "first_name":"",
   "last_name":"",
   "age":"",
   "dob":"",
   "address":[
      {
         "address1":"",
         "address2":""
      }
   ],
   "mobile":"",
   "telephone":"",
   "education":[
       {
          "primary_education":"",
          "seconday_education":"",
          "high_school":"",
          "university":""
       }
   ],
   "work_experience":[
       {
          "company_name":"",
          "company_address":"",
          "position":"",
          "joined_date":"",
          "resigned_date":""
       },
       {
          "company_name":"",
          "company_address":"",
          "position":"",
          "joined_date":"",
          "resigned_date":""
       }
   ]
}

test =  {
   "first_name":"asdfsf",
   "last_name":"",
   "age":"",
   "dob":"",
   "address":[
      {
         "address1":"",
         "address2":""
      }
   ],
   "mobile":"",
   "telephone":"",
   "education":[
       {
          "primary_education":"",
          "seconday_education":"",
          "high_school":"",
          "university":""
       }
   ],
   "work_experience":[
       {
          "company_name":"",
          "company_address":"",
          "position":"",
          "joined_date":"",
          "resigned_date":""
       },
       {
          "company_name":"",
          "company_address":"",
          "position":"",
          "joined_date":"sdfsfd",
          "resigned_date":""
       }
   ]
}

# I'm using lists of tuples because I can't use a dictionary (having the same key will just overwrite it). Eg: 'company name' repeats    
tuple_list = []
for k, v  in spine.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        # print(k,v)
        tuple_list.append((k,v))
    else:
        for l in v:
            for k, v  in l.items():
                # print(k,v)
                tuple_list.append((k,v))
                
tuple_list1 = []
for k, v  in test.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        # print(k,v)
        tuple_list1.append((k,v))
    else:
        for l in v:
            for k, v  in l.items():
                # print(k,v)
                tuple_list1.append((k,v))

for i, t in enumerate(tuple_list):
    print(i, t)
    if t == tuple_list1[i]:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Outupt: notice the two Falses, which are mismatched in the datasets

```
0 ('first_name', '')
False
1 ('last_name', '')
True
2 ('age', '')
True
3 ('dob', '')
True
4 ('address1', '')
True
5 ('address2', '')
True
6 ('mobile', '')
True
7 ('telephone', '')
True
8 ('primary_education', '')
True
9 ('seconday_education', '')
True
10 ('high_school', '')
True
11 ('university', '')
True
12 ('company_name', '')
True
13 ('company_address', '')
True
14 ('position', '')
True
15 ('joined_date', '')
True
16 ('resigned_date', '')
True
17 ('company_name', '')
True
18 ('company_address', '')
True
19 ('position', '')
True
20 ('joined_date', '')
False
21 ('resigned_date', '')
True
```